# Semantic UI - floated button affecting grid margin

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/3tL9msap/2

The right margin of the grid is pushed inwards by the width of the button.

Now see without the button http://jsfiddle.net/3tL9msap/3 where the grid margins are equal on both sides, as expected.

This button still has this effect even if the `<h1>` and `<button>` are placed in their own `<div class="ui container">` at the top.

If this behavior is expected, how can I right-align the button without affecting the grid margin?

HTML:

```
<div class="ui container">
    <button class="ui right floated primary button"><i class="plus icon"></i> New entry</button>
    <h1>Why you hate me, button?</h1>
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="stretched row">
            <div class="twelve wide column">
                <div class="ui segment">Left column</div>
            </div>
            <div class="four wide column">
                <div class="ui segment">
                    <h3>Elliot Fu</h3>
                    <p>Friends of Veronika</p>
                    <div class="ui two buttons">
                        <div class="ui basic green button">Approve</div>
                        <div class="ui basic red button">Decline</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the first one does not look "fine" but what does that mean? I can complain about your "fine" example, too. What do you mean by "weird behavior"? And a bug in what?

Comment: This is expected...you must clear the float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a expected behavior, you need to clear the float used by the button

**HTML WITH CSS INLINE (example)**

```
  <div class="ui grid" style="clear:both;">
        <div class="stretched row">
            <div class="twelve wide column">
                <div class="ui segment">Left column</div>
            </div>
            <div class="four wide column">
                <div class="ui segment">
                     <h3>Elliot Fu</h3>

                    <p>Friends of Veronika</p>
                    <div class="ui two buttons">
                        <div class="ui basic green button">Approve</div>
                        <div class="ui basic red button">Decline</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/3tL9msap/5/)**